# Selenium won't open specific chrome profile python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I have a chrome profile (*called Profile 1*) which I would like to control with Selenium. Whenever I try to open that chrome profile, Chrome opens **without** my profile, like it was my very first time opening Chrome.
My code is the following:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ákos\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\pythonScriptjeim\\chromedriver.exe", options=options,)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Funny thing is if i delete Profile 1 from the end like this, Chrome opens with my **default** profile:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ákos\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

So my problem is, that anything written after **User Data** doesn't seem to have any effects on chrome.
Any suggestions on how I could open the profile i'd like to control?